# how do i seperate two numbers in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

how do I separate two numbers if the length of the number is 18 . what I exactly wanna do is I want to separate mobile number(10) and landline number(8) when they are joined(18).

I have tried to extract first 8 numbers but I don't know how to apply condition. and I need to remove first 8 numbers if the condition satisfies

```
df['Landline'] = df['Number'].str[:8]
```

I have tried this but I know its wrong
`df['Landline'] = df['Number'].apply(lambda x : x.str[:8] if len(x)==18 )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need

```
df['Landline'] = df['Number'].apply(lambda x : x[:8] if len(x)==18 else x)
```

Comment: instead of else x how do I get Na ?

Comment: `df['Number'].apply(lambda x : x[:8] if len(x)==18 else np.nan)`?

Answer (score 2):

For extracting first 8 numbers, use `findall`.

```py
df['Number'].str.findall('^\d{8}')
```

#### Solution using an example

Here we use the **Dummy Data** made in the following section.

```py
# separate landline and mobile numbers
phone_numbers = df.Numbers.str.findall('(^\d{8})*(\d{10})').tolist()
# store in a dict
d = dict((i, {'Landline': e[0][0], 'Mobile': e[0][1]}) for i, e in enumerate(phone_numbers))
# make a temporary dataframe
phone_df = pd.DataFrame(d).T
# update original dataframe
df['Landline'] = phone_df['Landline']
df['Mobile'] = phone_df['Mobile']
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
              Numbers  Landline      Mobile
0  123456780123456789  12345678  0123456789
1          0123456789            0123456789
```

> #### Dummy Data

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Numbers': ['123456780123456789', '0123456789', ]})
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
              Numbers
0  123456780123456789
1          0123456789
```

Comment: df['Landline'] = df['Number'].str[:8]

Comment: I know how to extract but I need it only if condition satisfies